# android list only updates on second set

Tags: android, list

i have a list that i'm passing it an array
then in a callback from an html function i update the data i entered to the list
using

```
.set
```

problem is if i do the .set once nothing happens i see a blank list, i don't even see the rows as i initialized them. 
but after i do .set another time right after it i see the list how i want it to be update

sometimes after the second set i still see a white list.

why is this strange  behavior ? what am i doing wrong ?

list definition:

```
 aligmentManagerClass = ((appContext) getApplication()).getAligmentManagerVar();

        aligmentManagerClass.initlizeBestPositionScreen(bestPositionCallback); // notifies the manager that we initlized best Position Screen

        final BestPositionListAdapter adapter = new BestPositionListAdapter(this, arrayOfBaseStations); // Create the adapter to convert the array to views

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bestPosition_layout_list); // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(this); // sets an item click on the list
```

and this is the actual list callback:

```
//CALLBACL for When wifi Is turned on or Not
    bestPositionCallbackInterface bestPositionCallback = new bestPositionCallbackInterface() {

        @Override
        public void bestPositionCallbck (int i, BestPositionListModel modelData, int listSize) {
            //IMPLEMENT THE SERVICE CODE HERE >

            if (listDataGenerated == false) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++) { // initlizes the aligment list Array List
                    arrayOfBaseStations.add(new BestPositionListModel("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"));
                }
                listDataGenerated = true;
            }


            arrayOfBaseStations.set(i, new BestPositionListModel( // We need to set everything first to aliminate an anoying android bug
                    String.valueOf (0),
                    String.valueOf (1),
                    String.valueOf (2),
                    String.valueOf (3),
                    String.valueOf (4),
                    String.valueOf (5),
                    String.valueOf (6),
                    String.valueOf (7),
                    String.valueOf (8),
                    String.valueOf (9)));

            arrayOfBaseStations.set(i, new BestPositionListModel( // this is the real value were adding
                    String.valueOf (modelData.channelSectorType),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.channelAngle),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.channelElvation),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.channelAntBeamWidth),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.channelShort),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.CBW),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.bestRSS),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.sectorID),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.avilableResurces),
                    String.valueOf (modelData.bestEffortHSU)));


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` after you add data to your list. have you tried it?

Comment: where did you add it?

Comment: changed my code after  your comment and added it after i added all the Strings.valueof.. part of my code, it's a really great comment !

Comment: well sort of, it sitll sometimes does that white screen where it just doesn't show anything and doesn't output an error message and i can't understand why

Comment: every now and then instead of starting the intent for the screen it errors the message: "Error inflating class <unknown>" i  unnderstood it's a deeper problem with the code, and really hard to debug

Comment: Just fixed the problem needed to add it on another 3 screens before and it cleared the problem